# Tetris Rotation Representation

Tags: rust, tetris

I'm watching a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=74UYWFNfR64) on how to make Tetris and I'm completely lost trying to understand how to represent the different rotations of pieces.

The tutorial references the [2009 Tetris Design Guide](https://github.com/frankkopp/Tetris/blob/master/2009%20Tetris%20Design%20Guideline.pdf), particularly the slide on Tetrimino Facings:

[image: Tetrimino facings]

Relevant Code in the video starts at 1:10:27

The below code represent tuples indicating coordinates at which every piece rotates around.

```
Kind::O => &[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)],
Kind::I => &[(-1, 0), (0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0)],
Kind::T => &[(-1, 0), (0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1)],
Kind::L => &[(-1, 0), (0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1)],
Kind::J => &[(-1, 1), (-1, 0), (0, 0), (1, 0)],
Kind::S => &[(-1, 0), (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)],
Kind::Z => &[(-1, 1), (0, 1), (0, 0), (1, 0)],
```

Can someone explain to me this representation system please?

Comment: here? https://youtu.be/74UYWFNfR64?t=5545

Comment: The rotation bit on flipping `y` with `x` and vice versa for doing rotations makes sense, but I'm struggling to understand the representation system for the different pieces. For instance for letter O which should be the easiest, (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1) makes no sense to me

Comment: It's the coordinates of the 4 "pixels" of O, where (0,0) is the center of rotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example with J `[(-1, 1), (-1, 0), (0, 0), (1, 0)]`:

```java
(y)
 3
 2
 1 A
 0 B C D
-1
  -1 0 1 2 (x)
```

where

```py
A = (-1, 1)
B = (-1, 0)
C = ( 0, 0)
D = ( 1, 0)
```

`(0,0)` (here `C`) is the center of rotation.

To rotate, do this transform for each block :

- clockwise: `(x, y)` => `(-y, x)`
- anticlockwise: `(x, y)` => `(y, -x)`

Comment: thank you so much!! this makes a lot more sense!!